# How to write a platform independent wrapper function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am using snprintf to send the output to the buffer. Using C++ 11 and for desktop application.

As of now I am doing it only for windows. But from now onwards it has to support for different platforms (Windows, Linux and Mac)

**To support for multiple platforms, I am planning to write a wrapper function with #if tags.**

**but here the challenge I am facing is, when invoking WrapperSprintf from different places of the project the number of parameters are different.**

**How to write a common wrapper that can be used from different places with different no of parameters passed to WrapperSprintf function?**

**I tried the wrapper function like as shown below. Please help me how to proceed with this:**

```
void WrapperSprintf( char buffer, const char *format, ... )
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
    _snprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format,...);
#else
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, ...);
#endif
}
```

**Calling WrapperSprintf function1:**

```
char m_systemTime[20];

char* CUPSManager ::getSystemTime()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

    WrapperSprintf(m_systemTime,"%d-%d-%d :%d:%d:%d" , timeinfo ->tm_year +1900,
             timeinfo ->tm_mon +1,
             timeinfo->tm_mday,
             timeinfo->tm_hour,
             timeinfo->tm_min,
             timeinfo->tm_sec);
    return m_systemTime;
}
```

**Calling WrapperSprintf function2:**

```
void getDevicePath()
{
    wstring strDevPath;
    strDevPath = (LPCWSTR)cDevicePath;
    char cDevPath[2048];
    WrapperSprintf(cDevPath,"%ls", strDevPath.c_str());
    int nPathLength = strlen(cDevPath);
...
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a wrapper do begin with? MSVC seems to support `snprintf` without the `_`. (And `_snprintf` is less safe; it doesn't null-terminate the string if the buffer is not long enough.)

Comment: Check out `va_list`, which is how C captures ellipsis' (`...`). However, why not use C++?

Comment: `snprintf` is a standard C++ function. Why do you need a wrapper for it?

Comment: This looks like C code.  Is not idiomatic C++ code.

Comment: I am writing a common wrapper function to use for cross platform.

Comment: When useing snprintf, getting the error "error C3861: 'snprintf': identifier not found". Then I changed to  "_snprintf", with this getting the error "error C4996: '_snprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _snprintf_s instead.". Finally I changed to "_snprintf_s". Can I use "_snprintf_s" with Windows C++ and "snprintf" with Linux C++?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, as you said ellipsis' feature is of type C, I prefer to use C++

Comment: @bolov `snprintf()` (with the n) was added in C++11 and/or C99. before that its implementation was not standard. It is quite common to see configuration checks to see if it is defined in the current language when you are writing portable code (as it is not always there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not write it like that:

```
void WrapperSprintf( char buffer, const char *format, ... )
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
    _snprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format,...);
#else
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, ...);
#endif
}
```

You don't need a function here. What you want is to select the correct function.
Rather do this:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define WrapperSprintf    _snprintf_s
#else
#define WrapperSprintf    snprintf
#endif
```

If you want to get complex and have the ability rearrange argumetns then we can take it one step further:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define WrapperSprintf(buffer, size, ...)    _snprintf_s(buffer, size, __VA_ARGS__)
#elif defined(_WIERDYSTEM)
#define WrapperSprintf(buffer, size, ...)    wierdsnprintf(size, buffer, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define WrapperSprintf(buffer, size, ...)    snprintf(buffer, size, __VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Note: `__VA_ARGS__` must match at least one argument (i.e. it can not match zero). So use if for "format and format-arguments" as potentially there may be zero "format-arguments" if there are no `%` markers in the format string.

Comment: Hi @Martin York, Thank you for the detailed information. If I use like you mentioned, will it work for different no of parameters in WrapperSprintf. Because from one place I am calling WrapperSprintf function with 7 parameters and from another place with 3 parameters like as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder Yes the `...` (elipses) will match 1 or more parameters and the `__VA_ARGS__` is how to place he `...` on the output side.

Comment: ok, thank you. I will try this. But instead as I proposed, can i place the code that you have provided in a common file. so that i can access that function from anywhere in the project?

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder Yes. Simply place the above in a header.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vsnprintf` and `_vsnprintf` instead of `snprintf` and `_snprintf` respectively inside `WrapperSprintf`. These functions uses variable argument list.

Reference:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsnprintf/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsnprintf-vsnprintf-vsnprintf-l-vsnwprintf-vsnwprintf-l?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

> ### How to write a platform independent wrapper function in C++?

**One way** is to **read the C++ standard** (e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) for C++11), or choose a more recent standard [such as C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), **and stick to functions mentioned there**.

**Another way is to write your C++ code above libraries** (such as [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) or [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) or [GTKmm](https://www.gtkmm.org/)) **providing an abstraction above all platforms you want to target.**

For freestanding C++ code [cross-compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) then running on embedded platforms (e.g. some port of [FreeNOS](https://github.com/nieklinnenbank/FreeNOS) to [RaspBerry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) 4, or some recent [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)), or to [AutoSar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUTOSAR)) this could be a technical challenge.

#### read carefully the documentation of *your* C++ compiler

Choose a good enough [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or others) to run your C++ compiler (and other programs, possibly your metaprograms).

#### Consider also a web interface to your C++ program.

Toolkits like [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [Libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion) come to mind (or just [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib)). Most desktop operating systems today have some web browser (like [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/), itself coded in C++).

## Consider also some [meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) approach :

### Write your small programs generating C++ code helping in portability.

**The [SWIG](http://swig.org/) generator might be useful  or inspirational** (see also as examples the [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) parser generator, The [Qt moc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html), the [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) project, the [FLTK](https://fltk.org/) toolkit for inspiration or search for [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) programs coded in C++). The [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) preprocessors could be useful too. Your metaprogram generating C++ code might be coded in [Python](https://python.org/), [Lua](https://lua.org/), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), or just C++, etc...

So enable warnings related to portability, if available from your C++ compiler. For [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), read [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). Consider using some static analyzer (e.g. the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or [Frama-C++](https://frama-c.com/), or [Coverity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverity), or [BugSeng](https://www.bugseng.com/) or perhaps [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) at end of 2020; see [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report) to help you.

Remember the old adage

### there is no such thing as [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) code, there are just some ported software....

<sup>attribution forgotten, but I read something like that in the previous century</sup>

Comment: Hi @Basile Starynkevitch,I want to write a common function in the common utility file that serves for windows, linux and we can invoke this function from across the project. Can I proceed the function (WrapperSprintf) like I tried?

Comment: For which C++ standard (C++11, C++14, C++17, C++20) and which C++ target implementation (Android, your own C++ operating system kernel, Windows, Linux, [FreeRTOS](http://freertos.org/), ......) and with which C++ compiler or cross-compiler? **details matter**, so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62114031/edit) *your question* please.

Comment: It is for C++ standard C++ 11 and it is for desktop application.

Comment: **Why can't you use  [Qt](http://qt.io/), or POCO, or Boost ?** And desktop on *which operating system* (Linux is not the same as Windows or Android)? **Please explain that *in written English* in your question. If you improve your question, I could vote to reopen it.**

Comment: What about using [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) and use the web browser as an interface to your program? **Please improve your question**

Comment: Do you target [FreeDOS](https://www.freedos.org/)? If you do, that should go into your question

Comment: Hi @Basile Starynkevitch, I am using QT framework to support for multiple platforms. And it is the desktop application (for windows, linux and mac)